# Element not being disabled

Tags: vue.js

I have previously successfully implement this behaviour but for some reason it's not working. I am fairly new to Vue.js and I might be missing something.

I have two radio buttons as such:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="loginRadio" id="frmLoginRadio" value="true" v-model="loginRadio" checked>
        No, I am new to this site
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="loginRadio" id="frmRegisterRadio" value="false" v-model="loginRadio">
        Yes, my password is:
    </label>
</div>
```

They both have a v-model of loginRadio which is initially set to false. When the second radio button is clicked, the disabled input button below should be enabled again.

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" :disabled="loginRadio">
```

However, for some reason, the only thing that is happening is this (when I used Chrome Debug)

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" disabled="false">
```

and the element stays disabled. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not use `v-bind:`for the `value` attribute of the input buttons

Therefore, `loginRadio` does not contain boolean values `true` or `false` (depending on selection), but strings: `"true"` and `"false"`

it should be enough to properly bind the value attribute on both input buttons:

```
:value="true"
:value="false"
```